# Ionic 3 Native Plugin Social Sharing Error: Plugin not installed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m using an Ionic 3 app, trying to get social sharing working.

I followed the steps to install the Ionic Native Social Sharing plugin from: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/social-sharing/

Ran:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/social-sharing@4
```

Imported the plugin (version 4.x.x) via my app module and added SocialSharing to the providers array.

Imported the plugin via my app.component using:

```
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';
```

Added to the constructor:

```
private socialSharing: SocialSharing
```

This share function, also in app.component is triggered via a button in the html (side menu):

```
async share() {
    try {
      // Pop the native social sharing sheet, allowing the user to choose how to share the app.
      await this.socialSharing.share(this.shareMessage, this.shareSubject, this.shareFile, this.getShareUrl());
      this.toast.show('Thanks for sharing!', 3000);
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
      alert(err);
    }
  }
```

I’m using platforms: ios, android and browser.

When I call the method from a build on a real device I get the error:

**"Plugin is not installed"**

Tried:

- Checking logs for installation errors. None seen.
- Reinstalled plugin.
- Checked plugin present using $ionic cordova plugin list. cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.7 “SocialSharing” is present.
- Removed and added all platforms again.
- Wrapped the share method inside a platform.ready().

Nothing seems to be working. I cannot get the app to recognise the plugin is installed!

PLEASE HELP! :slight_smile: What can I try next?

Thanks

$ionic info:

Ionic:

Ionic CLI          : 5.2.3 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.5
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0, browser 6.0.0, ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic 5.4.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.5.1, (and 13 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.4.0 (update available: 0.6.0)
   native-run  : not installed

System:

ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v11.2.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.2.0/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.9.2
   OS         : macOS Mojave
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.2 Build version 10E125

Comment: can you do Ionic info or run another command that shows exactly the versions of ionic you are using?

Comment: Hi Sergey, I've edited the above with my ionic info. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1):

So according to your information your current installed plugin is version 5.4.7, to make plugins work with Ionic 3 you need to ensure you have installed 4.* version of the plugin.

Seems like you are using the right command for the install (adding @4 after the plugin install command).

Can you try uninstall the plugin and then attempt to reinstall and note which version its installing. You may have to try and install 4.* version:

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/social-sharing@4.12.0
```

Comment: I ran $ npm install --save @ionic-native/social-sharing@4.3.19, but got a "No matching version found" error. When I checked NPM it doesn't look like any version below 5 is available: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing. Out of interest, where did you see 4.3.19? Any idea what I can do next? Thanks

Comment: try npm install --save @ionic-native/social-sharing@4.12.0 - just tested it still exists;)

Comment: If I run $ npm install --save @ionic-native/social-sharing@4, I get: "+ @ionic-native/social-sharing@4.20.0 added 1 package from 1 contributor".

Comment: Immediately after, if I run $ ionic cordova plugin info I get: "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.7 "SocialSharing". It's the same after manually installing version 4.12.0.

Comment: can you try and explcitely uninstall that 5.4.7?  something like  npm uninstall @ionic-native/social-sharing@5.4.7.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. From what I can see, the npm package is 4.20.0 and the cordova plugin is 5.4.7. My package.json has the following 2 dependencies: 1) "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "4.20.0" and 2) "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.7". The cordova plugin is not added to config.xml (not sure if that is correct?). Have you got social sharing working on an Ionic 3 project? Another complication is that I'm using Ionic Appflow to perform web builds of my project so I wonder if that is a factor? Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, I just downloaded the Ionic Devapp as I see that the cordova social sharing plugin is supported. When running the app on the devapp app, it works! The social sharing sheet pops up as expected. I guess this must be an issue with the Ionic Pro/Appflow web build / pro deploy but still don't know what to try :(

Answer (score 0):

I got an issue with cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing in Ionic3 and main issue was couldn't install cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing plugin properly(error: can't find plugin.xml for es6-promise-plugin).

Steps to fix:

1. Installed es6-promise-plugin : ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/vstirbu/PromisesPlugin
2. Installed cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing : ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
3. npm install --save @ionic-native/social-sharing@4